# iframe anchors causes scroll of parent document in Safari (window, mac)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

**The scenario:**

I'm creating a mobile app promotion website in which I'm embedding a prototype inside an iframe, created by MarvelApp website

This prototype works fine in Firefox and chrome but it's causing a frustrating problem in Safari on Windows and Mac.

**The Problem:**
When ever an hash link is clicked inside that prototype, it causes my document to scroll to a random position.

Here is a sample for your reference:
http://54.85.152.70/safari-iframe-issue/

Click on those three dots and you'll see what I mean.

You can download the code from following url (in case you want to try):
http://54.85.152.70/safari-iframe-issue/safari-iframe-issue.zip

I searched for the solutions and I tried that but it didn't work. I'm not able to post that url as I don't have enough reputation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I searched for the solutions and I tried that but it didn't work.
Here is the url:
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?212032-The-DiggBar-iframes-and-anchors

Comment: Script inside the iframe is likely affecting parent scrollTop

Comment: @charlietfl yes that's what I think but the question is how to stop it. Any suggestions?